# Last Logons appear differently on 3 different domain controllers (one domain)

Tags: windows, authentication

The attributes for following properties are all different on all 3 dc's: Last Logon, Last Logoff, Last Bad Logon and Logon Count.

With my limited technical knowledge, I've been told users can be authenticated by any of the 3 dc's which are on the domain.

So my question is: why do the dc's not synchronize?

Please enlighten me good people

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Because they do not, as it is written in the documentation.

Last Login information is giving you the last logon for that particular DC. It is not considered an attribute worth synchronizing.

Answer (score 3):

Blast this 50 rep for comments - anyways TomTom is correct. These properties were being updated too often and it was causing too much replication traffic, back when bandwidth was expensive. LastLogon is updated per DC and does not replicate. LastLogonTimestamp is also updated per DC and replicates only after it's beyond 14 days in it's own database.

So you used to have to query LastLogon for all DCs to find the true lastlogon date. Now, using LastLogonTimestamp you only have to query 1 DC, as long as you're not looking for the last logon within the past 14 days.

For the count properties it tracks the number per DC and is not replicated, you'll have to combine those counts from all the DCs, although it isn't entirely accurate if you've ever had to decomission a DC - those counts are gone forever.

Here's how I verify there are no replication errors:

```
Repadmin /replsum
   Source DSA          largest delta    fails/total %%   error
    DC5                57m:19s    0 /   8    0
   Destination DSA     largest delta    fails/total %%   error
    DC5                55m:33s    0 /   8    0

Repadmin /showrepl * | findstr /i attempt
    Last attempt @ 2017-10-28 14:50:48 was successful.
    Last attempt @ 2017-10-28 14:50:54 was successful.
    Last attempt @ 2017-10-28 13:53:50 was successful.
```

Comment: +1 Always good to know the history and the details!